# xpra server error (error accepting new connection)

Tags: raspbian, linux

I'm having trouble connecting to my xpra server. I've installed Xpra version v0.14.10, on my raspberry pi 2 which running on Raspbian Jessie Distro.

I connect to my RPi through putty with X11 forwarding Enabled, and X display location being: `localhost:0:0`

I run the command:

`sudo xpra start :1337 --start-child=xterm --bind-tcp=0.0.0.0:1337`

on the server side (RPi) and on my windows I try connecting to the xpra server using the Xpra Launcher. My settings are:

```
Mode: TCP
Encoding: H.264
Quality: Auto
Speed: Auto
192.168.0.24 : 1337
No password
```

When I try to connect it outputs an error in red:

```
server requested disconnect: server error (error accepting new connection)
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before? How do you fix it? Thank you.